# VoiceOver and Scrolling in OpenGL backed UIViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, accessibility, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I am looking for advice on how to make a scrollable list drawn with OpenGL into a CAEAGLLayer backed UIViews accessible with VoiceOver. Ideally, the scrollable list in OpenGL should behave just like a native UIScrollView:

1. When the user swipes left/right with three fingers I want to scroll up/down a page. This behavior is easily achieved by implementing the [accessibilityScroll:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615161-accessibilityscroll) method.
2. When the user swipes left/right with one finger to go through all items in the list and the accessibility focus moves to the last/first partially visible item of the list I want the list to scroll slightly to ensure that the newly focused item is fully visible.
3. When the user taps directly on the last/first partially visible item of the list to move the accessibility focus directly to it I want no scroll action to happen.
4. When the user continues to swipe left/right with one finger while the last/first partially visible item of the list is selected, I want the list to scroll up/down one page to reveal previously hidden items.

As I said above, I know how to implement item #1, but after extensively studying [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/accessibility/uiaccessibility?language=objc) I still have no idea how to make items #2 to #4 work with the iOS accessibility API. I do think that those items are important for a great accessibility experience, though.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIAccessibility` is an informal protocol that vends the data necessary for accessibility clients such as VoiceOver to interpret and navigate a user interface. UIKit classes implement the full suite of methods in this protocol, rendering most views accessible by default. However, interface elements that aren't directly backed by a `UIView`, such as the view containing your `CAEAGLLayer`, must *manually* implement all relevant accessibility methods.

The best, and often only, way to render this content accessible is to implement a shadow hierarchy of [`UIAccessibilityElement`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilityelement) objects corresponding to the content of the scene. To do so, you must declare the `UIView` in the UIKit view hierarchy to be a [`UIAccessibilityContainer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/accessibility/uiaccessibilitycontainer). This is a two step process. First, you must ensure that the view backing your container is not, itself, an accessibility element, either by setting or overriding `isAccessibilityElement` to return `false`. Second, you must implement the four methods defined in the informal `UIAccessibilityContainer` protocol for accessing child accessibility elements:

- `func accessibilityElementCount()`
- `func index(ofAccessibilityElement element: Any)`
- `func index(ofAccessibilityElement: Any)`
- `var accessibilityElements: [Any]?`

In most cases, you will want to maintain an array of `UIAccessibilityElement` objects, each representing one component of your custom-rendered user interface. This array can be used to fulfill your backing view’s contract as an `UIAccessibilityContainer`. You can then extend elements to behave like scroll views, buttons, and other controls using methods in the `UIAccessibility` protocol.

To accomplish #1, you will want to implement `accessibiilityScroll()` on the an element in your accessibility hierarchy to respond to scrolling actions, returning `true` and posting a `UIAccessibilityPageScrolledNotification` with a string parameter describing the new scroll position. It sounds like you have this part working without issue.

Requirements #2, #3, and #4 all require programmatically scrolling your view when an element receives focus (or, in the case of #3, opting to do nothing). This can be accomplished using the [`UIAccessibilityFocus`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/accessibility/uiaccessibilityfocus) informal protocol. In particular, each element can respond to the  `func accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused()` and communicate its focus status back up to the object responsible for scrolling the view. If this triggers a paginated scroll, don't forget to post the page scrolled notification discussed, above.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am aware of how `UIAccessibility` works in general. My question is how do I make an `UIAccessibilityElement` behave like a scroll view with the requirements outlined in my questions? Or, to put it into your words: How exactly do I extend elements to behave like scroll views using methods in the `UIAccessibility` protocol? Do you have an example for that?

Comment: @Goderbauer I've edited the answer. Let me know if anything's still ambiguous!

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I am wondering, how do I differentiate between "`accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused` was called because the user tapped on the element" (#3) and "`accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused` was called because the user used swipe left/right to get to that element" (#2 and #4). That differentiation will be important to figure out if I should scroll or not.

Comment: @Goderbauer You cannot infer how a user reached the element. May I ask why this is a significant difference to users? Consider only paging the view when you reach an item that is fully offscreen. Users can always scroll the manually if asked by a sighted user to reveal something partially offscreen.

Comment: You're right, it's not super important, but would be nice to have to fully simulate native behavior. Your suggestions seems to be the best I can do given the limited API. I am marking your answer as accepted.